# Why can't I change border and background-color of my checkbox? For selector used I can only just to modify eg. height, width

Tags: css, input

HTML:

```
<div class="first-label-container">     
<label class="label-first label-common"><input type="checkbox" class="check-box" name="check" value="check"/> born in the real world</label>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
    width: 16px; // working
    height: 16px; // working
    border: 5px solid #4d90cb; // not working
    border-radius: 5px;  // not working
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a new solution for you. You need to change both the element and the style.

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .label-first:after {
  content: '✔';
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  left: 4px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 0.8;
  color: #09ad7e;
  transition: all .2s;
}
.label-first {
  padding-left: 30px;
  position: relative;
}
.label-first:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  border: 2px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="first-label-container">
  <input type="checkbox" class="check-box" name="check" checked id="checkbox" />
  <label class="label-first label-common" for="checkbox">born in the real world</label>
</div>
```

I hope it can help you.

Comment: Thanks meucaa. Hehe